# Populate list of multiples using stream

Tags: java, java-stream, declarative-programming

Is there a way to write this method in a Java 8 declarative style, using stream()?

```
public List<Integer> getFives(int numberOfElements, int incrementNum) {
    List<Integer> list;
    int value = incrementNum;
    list.add(value);
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfElements; i++) {
        value = value + incrementNum;
        list.add(value);
    }
    return list;
}
```

Comment: Your current code does not compile. What do you what to achieve? And what have you tried?

Comment: Why do you want to write it using streams?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to achieve what you want, one of them is using `Intstream#iterate` :

```
public static  List<Integer> getFives(int numberOfElements, int incrementNum) {    
    return IntStream.iterate(incrementNum, i -> i+incrementNum)
                    .limit(numberOfElements)
                    .boxed()
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Comment: according to the code in question, choose seed as `incrementNum`

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be looking for multiples as:

```
public List<Integer> getMultiples(int numberOfElements, int incrementNum) {
    return IntStream.rangeClosed(1, numberOfElements)
            .mapToObj(i -> i * incrementNum)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```